# Fenics : looking forward to compute displacements at nodes

Tags: python, fenics

I just went through the Fenics book to get the nodal displacements and tried this code ....

```
u_nodal_values = U.vector()
u_array = u_nodal_values.array()
coor = mesh.coordinates()
center = (0.5,0.5,0.5)
print U(center)
if mesh.num_vertices()==len(u_array):
   for i in range(mesh.num_vertices()): 
       print ’U(%8g,%8g,%8g) = %g’% (coor[i][0], coor[i][1], u_array[i])
```

but i don't get the expected result..
can anyone suggest me the modification ??

Comment: Welcome to scicomp! It would help if you could tell us what the expected result was. To make helping you easier, you should also give a *complete* example, i.e., one we can copy and paste and compare the results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are relying on a specific DOF ordering, which was changed in release 1.1. However, the vertex to DOF map which you need to solve your problem can be obtained by the following code

```
map = V.dofmap().vertex_to_dof_map(mesh)
```

Comment: when I use your information in my code i get error as vertex_to_dof = V.dofmap().vertex_to_dof_map(mesh)
AttributeError: 'GenericDofMap' object has no attribute 'vertex_to_dof_map'....

Comment: Which version of DOLFIN are you using? I am on 1.2.0 and it works fine. But as far as I know this feature was also backported to 1.1.x. Perhaps you should update your FEniCS packages.

Comment: I upgraded my fenics and now it works perfectly thnks

Comment: In 2019.1.0 it is `vertex_to_dof_map(V)`